Some feature modules of your app bundle exceed the maximum compressed download size (200 MB). Reduce the sizes of these modules: base
I must upload game to Google Play Console but it shows this error
"Some feature modules of your app bundle exceed the maximum compressed download size (200 MB). Reduce the sizes of these modules: base."
and when Building this alert saying: "The download sizes of APKs generated from your App Bundle will be 252-252 MB for "base" module.
Google Play store accepts apps with "base" module up to 200 MB."
(My Build Size of .abb is 280mb and base module is 250mb need to 200mb to be able to upload to GooglePlayConsole)
I tried to build through build settings with split application ticked
I tried to build through Google>Build App Bundle
Reduce size of build by optimizing textures but need to do more.
But none worked,
(I don't want to upload to server using Asset Bundle feature.)
Any Help or there is no hope.

I have reduced size by 10-20% just by renaming Resources Folders that I don't use.

Why do you have a Resources folder if you don't use it?

Not found any other answers and just optimized till 200mb and uploaded successfully
